# Name Error and traceback error on class methods and static methods?

Tags: python

I'm not to sure why but I am getting a Name Error Employee which is not defined yet it is as a class name. I am also getting a traceback error and not to sure why. Would love some help on this!

https://repl.it/repls/UnwieldyHorribleJavadoc

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0;
    raise_amt = 1.4;

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

        Employee.num_of_emps += 1;
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)

    def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
      cls.raise_amt = amount


    emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Smith', 5000)
    emp_2 = Employee('Thomas', 'Hunt', 7000)

    Employee.set_raise_amt(1.05)

    print(Employee.raise_amt)
    print(emp_1.raise_amt)
    print(emp_2.raise_amt)
```

Comment: It is not a "traceback error" but an "error traceback" which contains helpful information about the error. And please add the full error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty simple. Whitespace is syntactically significant in Python. The things you are intending to happen after the class definition are happening during the class definition (and attempting to reference the class you are defining).

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0;
    raise_amt = 1.4;

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

        Employee.num_of_emps += 1;
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)

    def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
      cls.raise_amt = amount

# <<<<< from here down, unindent your code 
# <<<<< to cause it to execute AFTER the class definition

emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Smith', 5000)
emp_2 = Employee('Thomas', 'Hunt', 7000)

Employee.set_raise_amt(1.05)

print(Employee.raise_amt)
print(emp_1.raise_amt)
print(emp_2.raise_amt)
```

There are other problems with your code, but this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors.

1. Indentation is important. `emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Smith', 5000)` and following lines are not part of the class, so should be deintended.
2. The way you are using it, `set_raise_amt(cls, amount)` should be a class method, it needs the proper decorator.

You can fix it like this:

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0;
    raise_amt = 1.4;

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

        Employee.num_of_emps += 1;
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)

    @classmethod
    def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
        cls.raise_amt = amount


emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Smith', 5000)
emp_2 = Employee('Thomas', 'Hunt', 7000)

Employee.set_raise_amt(1.05)

print(Employee.raise_amt)
print(emp_1.raise_amt)
print(emp_2.raise_amt)
```

Not sure if this is really what you want to do, but this runs without errors and prints `1.05` three times.